# Getting "Cannot read properties of undefined" when calling imported class's method

Tags: typescript

I'm getting a "Cannot read properties of undefined" when calling an imported class's method in Typescript (Angular 15). The actual error is

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'HmacSHA1')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'HmacSHA1')
    at AuthenticationService.setCookies (authentication.service.ts:93:21)
    at AuthenticationService.login (authentication.service.ts:72:8)
    at new LoginComponent (login.component.ts:16:34)
    at NodeInjectorFactory.LoginComponent_Factory [as factory] (login.component.ts:11:28)
    at getNodeInjectable (core.mjs:3485:44)
    at createRootComponent (core.mjs:12391:35)
    at ComponentFactory.create (core.mjs:12272:25)
    at ViewContainerRef.createComponent (core.mjs:21416:47)
    at RouterOutlet.activateWith (router.mjs:2636:39)
    at ActivateRoutes.activateRoutes (router.mjs:3048:40)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:1211:31)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:1165:17)
    at zone.js:1278:17
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:406:31)
    at core.mjs:23999:55
    at AsyncStackTaggingZoneSpec.onInvokeTask (core.mjs:23999:36)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:405:60)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.mjs:24300:33)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:405:60)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:178:47)
```

`CryptoJS` is imported as follows:

```
import { CryptoJS } from 'crypto-js';
```

The failing line (`authentication.service.ts:93`) is:

```
            const HmacHash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA1(currentUser, Date.now().toString());
```

I have verified that `currentUser` is a valid string (that is, it's not undefined).  It's seems as though `CryptoJS` is undefined, though I don't understand how that could be. Note that `CryptoJS` is the name of the class rather than a variable referencing an instance of the class. This has worked for us before, so I don't believe this is the cause of the error.

Another thing to note is that the failing call to `CryptoJS.HmacSHA1()` is made indirectly from the `LoginComponent` constructor.  Could that somehow be causing `CryptoJS` to be undefined?

Comment: Please give a [mre].

Comment: A quick answer to your question is simply to `console.log("Crypto", CryptoJS)`.  Because the error implies that `CryptoJS` is undefined in the context where you access it.

Comment: Your first thing to check should have been [the docs](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js?tab=readme-ov-file#usage)... `import { hmacSHA1 } from 'crypto-js/hmac-sha1'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I simply needed to change the import statement from

```
import { CryptoJS } from 'crypto-js';
```

to

```
import CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';
```

I'm new to TypeScript and didn't realize that the two import statements have different meanings.

**FYI**: `import { CryptoJS } from 'crypto-js';` is a [named import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#named_import), while `import CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';` is a [default import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#default_import).  There are actually four import types, see the [MDM JavaScript import documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#forms_of_import_declarations) for details.